# How do I trigger the "Next" option between 4 input fields?

Tags: javascript, variables, keyboard-events

I have a simple web-app for inputting a few text fields and then outputting those fields into an image. Currently, the variables are set up to only take uppercase alpha (no punctuation or numbers) but the fields do not trigger the built-in keyboard's `Next` option to auto advance to the next variable input field, requiring the user to click each box individually.

Is there a specific trigger in the input type between the Android/ Samsung/Apple keyboards that makes the phone see the set on inputs as connected to enable a user to just hit enter/next? Tab works fine on PC.

Example code of the input:

```html
<input pattern="[A-Z]*" style="text-transform: uppercase;" type="text" name="d" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^A-z]/g,'');" id="d">
```

Answer (score 0):

As i get it from your question, you want the input to 'focus' on the next input when they press enter on a phone?

"e.which !== 13":: 13 is the enter key on the keyboard

```js
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.which !== 13) {
    return;
  }

  const target = e.target;
  const form = target.closest('form');
  if (!form) {
    return;
  }

  const focusable = Array.from(form.querySelectorAll('input, select')).filter(function(element) {
    return window.getComputedStyle(element).display !== 'none';
  });
  const currentIndex = focusable.indexOf(target);
  const next = focusable[currentIndex + 1];
  if (next) {
    next.focus();
  }

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" />
  <br>
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="text" id="email" />
  <br>
  <label for "age">Age:</label>
  <input type="text" id="age" />
  <br>
  <label for="country">Country:</label>
  <select id="country">
    <option value="us">United States</option>
    <option value="ca">Canada</option>
    <option value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I will try this and report back